# Can each user have a different layout in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I am new to Liferay and currently I (as an admin) set the visible portlets and their position on the page. Firstly, only I can change the layout. Secondly, all users see the same layout. That's not exactly what I want.

Is it possible in Liferay 6.1.0 to have each user of the portal be able to set her own portlet composition (both *which* portlets, and *where* they should be displayed)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page Customizations are a new feature in Liferay 6.1. With Page Customizations, any user can create personalized versions of any public page that has customizations enabled. Customizations are based on the rows and columns of a page layout. Administrators can activate or deactivate customizations for any row or column on any page. When users customize a page, they have the option to use either their version or the default version of a page. Users can't see alternate versions of pages other than their own.

When an administrator activates Page Customizations for a page, any portlets that are in a Customizable row or column can be moved around the page or removed from the page. Users can add new portlets of their own choosing to the page. If at any time users determine that they don't like their customizations, they can click Reset My Customizations to revert their pages back to the default.

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/page-creation-and-manageme-3

Comment: You can manipulate the page customizations by clicking Manage on the dockbar while signed in as an admin

Comment: Which privileges are needed for a user to be able to customize her view? A fresh user can't do that - I've just checked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very much possible that each user can have different layout in Liferay. But, you need to create a user page for that.

Liferay supports user personalization, so that means, each user can have his/her own sites,pages either public or private.

If you are working on the vanilla instance of Liferay, then you might notice that in the admin/liferay dock bar, each user have option to select his/her own set of public/private page.

User can modify, add portlet, change layout even change themes on that.

But,

if you want to do this all on some common page, then that page will not be common, in this case, you might have to create a copy of that particular page per use.